# Regex Retrieving data after a lookahead

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to be able to retrieve `!$£` from this string: `(?i).*!$abc£`

I have written the following Regex expression:

```
`(?<=\(\?i\)..)[^a-zA-Z0-9\s:]*
```

but for some reason it only matches `!$` from the string despite if the match is seperated from the lookahead it matches perfectly.

how do i fix this?

this is javascript regex

Comment: You can use: `s = s.replace(/\(\?i\)..(\W*)\w+/, '$1')`

Comment: Try `text.replace(/\(\?i\)..([^\w\s:]*)\w+(\W*)/, '$1$2')`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ucPyfE/1).

Comment: thank you @WiktorStribiżew that worked, do you know why mine didn't work? if not thats ok thanks for solving my problem for me

Comment: @beep There can be two issues: you are probably using a regex constructor notation without escaping regex metacharacters properly (using double backslashes), or your environment does not support lookbehinds.

Comment: @beep: How do you want to handle `(?i).*!$abc£aa$bb` ?

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `replace` code in javascript with a regex that matches `($i)..` and grabs remaining non-whitespace string in a capture group. Then we use a replacer that removes all word characters from the captured group value.

```js
var s = '(?i).*!$abc£aa$bb'
var r = s.replace(/\(\?i\)..(\S+)/, (m, g1) => {
   return g1.replace(/\w+/g, '')});
console.log(r)
//=> !$£$
```

Answer (score 2):

```
/[^!$£]/g
```

Replace everything but !, $, and £.

```js
const str = `(?i).*!$abc£`;

const rgx = /[^!$£]/g;

const res = str.replaceAll(rgx, '');

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
text = text.replace(/\(\?i\)..([^\w\s:]*)\w+(\W*)/, '$1$2')
// or even
text = text.replace(/\(\?i\)..([^\w\s:]*)\w+/, '$1')
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/ucPyfE/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/ucPyfE/2)

*Details*:

- `\(\?i\)` - a `(?i)` string
- `..` -  any two chars other than line break chars
- `([^\w\s:]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): zero or more chars other than word, whitespace and `:` chars
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(\W*)` - Group 2: zero or more non-word chars.

The replacement is the concatenation of Group 1 and Group 2.